# application/octet-stream for file Upload

Tags: java, spring, file, upload, mime-types

In a Spring Boot app, I am trying to filter file types when use upload file by using the following approach:

```
public static void validateFile(InputStream inputStream, String fileId) throws FileUploadException {
    try {
          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

          AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
          Detector detector = parser.getDetector();
          Metadata md = new Metadata();
          md.add(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileId);
          MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(bis, md);

          // check if mediaType.toString() is in my valid file types ("audio/opus", "audio/x-aac", ...)
          

    } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new Exception(fileId);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to add a file wit the extension of `aac`,the file type would be `application/octet-stream`.

According to [Common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types), `application/octet-stream` is the default value for all other cases (I think when file type is not detected).

So, in this situation, should I add `application/octet-stream` type to my valid file types list? I know it may be dangerous in some cases, but how can I filter the file types for audio/video?

Note: I used some pages while building my valid file type list e.g. https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xml

Comment: Does anybody else have no idea?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I will do is give a short and concise run-through/implementation of Tika.

Below is the code for a method you can use to find the type of the document:

```
public static String detectDocTypeUsingDetector(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException {
    Detector detector = new DefaultDetector();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
 
    MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
    return mediaType.toString();
}
```

This java code will return the document type. Even if the extension of the file has been changed, Tika can still identify the correct type using the magic bytes it finds at the beginning of the file.

Another easier way to do this is through the facade Tika class:

```
public static String detectDocTypeUsingFacade(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException {
  
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String mediaType = tika.detect(stream);
    return mediaType;
}
```

Next, let us extract the file’s contents using a parser.

```
public static String extractContentUsingParser(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException {
  
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
 
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
    return handler.toString();
}
```

This is a higher level approach that shows what is going on but again, we can use the Tika class for an easier approach:

```
public static String extractContentUsingFacade(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException, TikaException {
  
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String content = tika.parseToString(stream);
    return content;
}
```

Next, let’s extract the metadata using the parser as well:

```
public static Metadata extractMetadatatUsingParser(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
  
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
 
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
    return metadata;
}
```

And again, we can make it easier:

```
public static Metadata extractMetadatatUsingFacade(InputStream stream) 
  throws IOException, TikaException {
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
 
    tika.parse(stream, metadata);
    return metadata;
}
```

Importing packages
Here are most of the things you need to import for these methods:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable and detailed helps. But I still get `application/octet-stream` as file type. On the other hand, the method throws excption when I do not set metadata using `metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileId);`. I also tried with this but the result is not changed. On the other hand,  when I use `Parser`  examples, the metadata value is empty string.

Comment: So, do you have any idea how can I get correct file type for aac instead of `application/octet-stream`? I think Tika Parser would be the solution as mentioned on https://tika.apache.org/1.5/detection.html#Container_Aware_Detection, but maybe we missed a little point and that's why metadata after parser is empty string. Any idea?